# Does mass gives a object/particle a decrease of time dilation and length contraction?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, speed-of-light

And that’s why a photon don’t experience time and distance because he experience total time dilation and length contraction?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Essentially yes, but not directly. A massless particle moves with the speed of light and does not "experience" time or distance because of the speed. A massive particle moves slower and "experiences" time and distance. Speed is the key here, but speed does depend on mass.

Comment: @safesphere,  Thank you. That a nice and clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to talk about time dilation for a massless particle. Usually when you calculate time dilation Δt=Δt_o/√(1-(v/c)^2) where Δt_0 is for a clock at rest, it does not require mass in the equation. If an object with mass approaches a black hole, time will move slower with an observer that is far away form a black hole. Also, when a photon passes from a massive object like a sun, it undergoes a shift in frequency. For a photon from a start going to a black hole, the photon would appear red shifted, because it is moving to a higher gravitational potential. Here is a link to a interesting wikipedia article. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift